# Angular JS ng-click not working when HTML loaded through another javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a javascript function that builds a tree from JSON data and creates a list of anchor tag elements like:

```html
<a ng-click="shareParent(4619)">Some data</a>
```

This list is populated after the page is loaded. This ng-click doesn't get registered at the controller. Here is my controller:

```js
catalog.controller('categoryTree', ['$scope',function($scope) {
    $scope.shareParent = function(parent) {
        console.log(parent)
      }
}]);
```

The data never shows up at the controller. I am a newbie, so I may be doing something really wrong here. I've even tried calling $scope.$apply(), but that doesn't do any good either.

The anchor element does have a controller associated with it and an ng-app is also declared. Just the ng-click isn't working.

---

EDIT:

Solved it using the following injector code in my controller after the DOM element was appended:

```
$injector = angular.element(document.querySelector('#categoryTree')).injector();
element = angular.element(document.querySelector('#category-tree'));
$injector.invoke(function ($compile) {
      var scope = element.scope();
      $compile(element)(scope);
   });
```

There may be a better way of doing this.

Comment: Have you used any controller for your view? Can you add complete code?

Comment: Complete code is very big, but yes there is a controller. Its called `categoryTree`

Comment: Make sure you have all the `a`s inside a `div` with `ng-controller="categoryTree"`. Also, why are you using a javascript function? You could use `ng-repeat`.

Comment: Because its a complicated tree using an API that gets data and then a heavy amount of manipulation which I don't think ng-repeat can help me with. The tree is built using simple javascript `createElement` functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create new HTML elements in Angular, you have to connect it to a scope. This is called `compiling`

For example:

```
function myController($scope,$compile,$element){

  //Creating New Element
  var newElement=$('<div ng-click=hello()>Hello World</div>')

  //Compile The Element, and assign it to current scope
  $compile(newElement)($scope)

  //Append the element, to wherever do you want. For example to current controller element
  newElement.appendTo($element)

  $scope.hello=function(){
     alert('It is working!')
  }
}
```

More Info: [Angular $compile service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)

Comment: So when I did this, i tried to bind the data using a `{[{child}]}` and ended up getting `{"0":{"jQuery1113034352644230239093":69},"context":{"jQuery1113034352644230239093":69},"length":1}` in response. Although the data in console seems fine.

Answer (score 2):

just try using `$compile() ($scope)`

something like

```
var domElement = $compile('your javascript to create dom elements')($scope);
```

and then you will need to append the DOM element to your page.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks quite okay. Have you bind the HTML to your controller `categoryTree`?

Comment: There is a binding. The problem is that all the new elements are rendered after the page is loaded. So maybe that's why angularJS isn't registering them?

Comment: I guess you need `compileService` to load external html like this https://github.com/stanleyxu2005/dashing/blob/master/src/tabset/tabset.js#L84

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use the simple on onclick and access functions and variables via angular element() ..... have fun ;)

```
angular.element(angular_app_controller_element).scope().var/function()
```